# GET of smidge'd scripts/css fails with 500 error - InternalCreateDirectory throws

Tags: asp.net-core, bundling-and-minification, smidge

Smidge 3.0.0

I am following the instructions in https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge to the tee. But havent been able to get smidge to work for me. I get a 500 error on GET of the bundle js/css files. After some digging in Chrome debugger, I was able to find that the error seems to be related to Smidge being unable to create the cache folders. Here's the stack - I repro'd it by just trying to navigate to the bundle JS file like this:

**GET http://localhost:8241/sb/app-scripts.js.v3**

results in:

**UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\PROJECTNAME\App_Data\Smidge\Cache\MACHINENAME\3' is denied.**
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int errorCode, string maybeFullPath)
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(string fullPath, string path, object dirSecurityObj, bool checkHost)
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(string path, bool checkHost)
Smidge.FileSystemHelper.GetCacheFilePath(IWebFile file, bool fileWatchEnabled, string extension, ICacheBuster cacheBuster, out Lazy fileInfo)
Smidge.FileProcessors.PreProcessManager+d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Smidge.FileProcessors.PreProcessManager+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Smidge.FileProcessors.PreProcessManager+d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Smidge.Controllers.SmidgeController+d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
lambda_method(Closure , object )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__12.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: Probably IIS is using a different account and when it is trying to access your user's folder it is failing due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: yes, that was it actually. This was because my aspnetcore EXE running as NETWORK SERVICE does not having enough permissions to create folders/files inside the solution folder. As you can notice, my repo is inside the c:/users folder (which is where VS puts the repo by default). The localgroup "ServiceFabricAllowedUsers" does contain NETWORK SERVICE account but that group also does not have write perms to my solution folder. I granted WRITE permissions to this localgroup to that folder and that solved it. I have posted a new issue on the smidge git repo and requested to document/fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS is running on a different account and it does not have permissions to write to your profile folders. Change the application so that it does not have to access profile folders or folders that require specific permissions.